# Eclipse as thin client for web app

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have seen several IBM client tools that use Eclipse as some sort of a "wrapper" for a web-based application. Is there any reference or base project I can use to create one of my own?

I understand that Eclipse has an the RCP SDK that allows doing this but I would prefer something as simple as just configuring it with the URL that it goes to when the application is launched.

Comment: Please share a link to an example of those "IBM client tools" to clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just define a RCP application with single View, that has a browser widget in it. So you can put whatever URL you want. Example [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html). But in that way you can also use only SWT. [Here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet128.java) is an example for the second one.